# find_dependency(Threads) or include(FindThreads) in a package config file

Tags: multithreading, cmake, installation, pthreads, buildconfiguration

In CMake, we can use [`find_dependency()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/module/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.html) in an package `-config.cmake` file to "forwards the correct parameters for QUIET and REQUIRED which were passed to the original `find_package()` call." So, naturally we'll want to do that instead of calling `find_package()` in such files.

Also, for dependency on a threads library, CMake offers us the [`FindThreads` module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/module/FindThreads.html?highlight=findthreads), so that we write `include(FindThreads)`, prepended by some preference commands, and get a bunch of interesting variables set. So, that's preferable to `find_package(Threads)`.

And thus we have a dilemma: What to put in `-config.cmake` files, for a threads library dependency? The former, or the latter?

Comment: "CMake offers us the FindThreads module, so that we write `include(FindThreads)`" - No, for all `FindXXX` modules provided by CMake the intended way for include them is `find_package(XXX)`. Inside other config/find scripts `find_package` is replaced with `find_dependency`, as usual.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Then I'm confused regarding how to use `FindThreads`. After including it, the target is already defined without me having to `find_package(Threads)`.

Comment: Hm, I meant `find_package(Threads)` should be used **instead** of `include(FindThreads)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: But that seems to contradict what the module documentation says, about the preference variables etc. You're actually saying not to use that module; so why even have it?

Comment: Do you mean `THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG` variable? This variable is intended to be set before `find_package(Threads)`, so it will affect on the module. BTW: https://github.com/apache/incubator-brpc/issues/1023

Comment: Actually, I cannot find **official** note from the CMake developers that `FindThreads` module should be used via `find_package()` instead of `include()`. But [implementation of this module](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindThreads.cmake) uses `FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS` macro, which is [intended to be used](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.html)  in [Find modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#find-modules), which in turn are usable via `find_package`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: ... which supports the usage pattern of "FindThreads instead of find_package(Threads)" :-(

Comment: If "FindThreads instead of find_package(Threads)" is a citation, could you provide its source? "You're actually saying not to use that module; so why even have it?" - `find_package(Threads)` actually **uses** `FindThreads` module. But before parsing the module as a script, `find_package` adjusts some variables (which are used e.g. by `FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS` macro). As opposite, the only effect of `include(FindThreads)` is parsing the module as a script, without setting additional variables.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I was paraphrasing myself with that quote. Anyway, if `find_package()` using `FindThreads`, that means it also supports the special setup variables, right? In that case, it's back to find_package for me.

Comment: Yes, if you set `THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG` variable, then futher `find_package(Threads)` call will handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Following a discussion in comments with @Tsyarev, it seems that:

- `find_package(Threads)` includes the `FindThreads` module internally.
- ... which means it "respects" the preference variables affecting `FindThreads` behavioe.

so it makes sense, functionally and aesthetically, to just use `find_package()` in your main `CMakeLists.txt` and `find_dependency()` in `-config.cmake`.